# How to return the order that an item appears in a list in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find out how to find the position that an item appears in a list. For example:

```
<ul>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
</ul>
```

If I clicked on item 2, I would want to receive '2'. Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's possible by using [jquery's index](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/index#subject).

**EDIT:**

```
<ul id="my_list">
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
</ul>
```

and in js,

```
var $my_list = $('#my_list');
$my_list.find('li').click(function(){
    var index = $('ul#my_list li').index(this);
    alert(index);
});
```

this should do what you need.

hope it helps, Sinan.

Answer (score 2):

you could assign them IDs like

```
<ul>
  <li id="1">item 1</li>
  <li id="2">item 2</li>
  <li id="3">item 3</li>
</ul>
```

then :

```
$("li").live('click', function(){ 
alert($(this).attr("id"));
}
```

or without IDs as Sinan says:

```
$("li").live('click', function(){ 
    alert($("li").index(this) + 1);
    }
```

+1 because indexing starts from 0

Comment: Without an id on the `ul`, this almost certainly won't do what he wants (see my answer).

Comment: @Dominic Rodger yes I saw your answer, well he got what he asked for .. so I'm not going to bother updating a question .. tnx for pointing that out to me though .. it might just be to me sometime soon

Answer (score 2):

```
$("ul#your_ul li").click(function () {
  // this is the dom element clicked
  var index = $("ul#your_ul li").index(this) + 1;
});
```

You need to give the `ul` you want to do this on an id - otherwise it'll return the index of the `li` in terms of all `li`s within `ul`s, which is not what you want.

Answer (score -1):

Pseudo code

```
$('ul > li').each(function(el) {

    el.ClickEvent(function() {

        alert(el.preceding-siblings.count() + 1);

    });
});
```

Something like that anyway, sorry didn't have time to get the syntax spot on

Comment: Won't that tell you how many `li`s there are within the `ul`, rather than the index of the clicked-on `li` within the `ul`?

Comment: Err yes, sorry I meant preceding-siblings

Comment: I don't think preceding-siblings is valid jQuery - am I missing something? Do you mean `prevAll` (http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/)?

Comment: Yes exactly, I said that the post wasn't 100% syntactically correct but the concept works, all the OP has to do is check the jquery api for the correct syntax

Answer (score -1):

```
okie i have edited my answer do this

$(function()
{
  var _item=1;
  $('ul li').each(function(){
  var _elm=$(this).attr('_elm',_item);
  }).bind('click',_handle);
  _item++;
});

function _myClick(e)
{
    var _yourValue=$(e.target).attr('_elm');
    //this is the value u were looking for
}
```